How to deploy office add-in if I have published web application (Angular + ASP.NET Core) and Manifest XML File?
Is there any proper stepwise description for publishing the Office Add-in?
I want to deploy it as Admin Managed using the Integrated Apps or any other method that requires the published web application for the Add-in and Manifest file.
I have gone through the documentation, if I missed please provide the proper steps or the documentation if anyone tried.

There are ways to deploy Office Add-ins for testing or distribution to users Methods.If you want to use the integrated app, you can use the Microsoft 365 admin center to distribute the add-in to users in your organization. This is done through the integrated app or central deployment.
Deploy your Office add-ins
Deploy an Office Add-in using the admin center
But first determine whether centralized deployment of add-ins is appropriate for your organization, you can refer to the following link: enter link description here
